# Why isn't my query updating?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query in my php file:

```
    if ($user) { //user is logged in (which he is)
        $highscore = mysql_query("SELECT highscore FROM highscore WHERE fbID = $user"); //wil give 200
        $fb_country_str = nl;

        if (mysql_num_rows($highscore) == 0) { //if no result from highscore set it to 1
            $highscore = 1;
        } else { //if we do get a result, select the country (in this case it is: uk)
            $country = mysql_query("SELECT country FROM highscore WHERE fbID = $user");
            if (!($country == $fb_country_str)) { //if the country is NOT the same, update the country with $fb_country_str (which in this case it should update)
                $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE highscore SET country = $fb_country_str WHERE fbID = $user");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when run, it doesn't update the database where country uk should be changed to nl. Why not? What am I missing?

Kind regards

Comment: Put your variables into `'`: `$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE highscore SET country = '$fb_country_str' WHERE fbID = '$user'");` It will prevent the query errors, when country contains more than one word.

Comment: And even more important - you should think about using PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) article will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) is a good PDO-related tutorial.

Comment: I was not aware of this PDO stuff, will do some reading into it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mysql_query function doesn't return a string, it will return a resource that you can use with other mysql_* functions (see http://php.net/mysql_query)

So your variable **$country** is not what you expect. You need to use a function like **mysql_fetch_assoc** or **mysql_result** to get the country string

you can see samples on the php.net man page and also you used the return value as a resource (and not a scalar value) already in that script when you called the mysql_num_rows function on **$highscore**

Answer (score 0):

```
   if ($user) { //user is logged in (which he is)
        $highscore = mysql_query("SELECT highscore FROM highscore WHERE fbID = $user"); //wil give 200
        $fb_country_str = "nl"; //It's a string , you need quotes.

        if (mysql_num_rows($highscore) == 0) { //if no result from highscore set it to 1
            $highscore = 1;
        } else { //if we do get a result, select the country (in this case it is: uk)
            $getCountry = mysql_query("SELECT country FROM highscore WHERE fbID = $user");
//NOTICE - COUNTRY IS NOT THE COUNTRY VALUE YET!
$country = mysql_fetch_array($country);
$country = $country['country'];
            if (!($country == $fb_country_str)) { //if the country is NOT the same, update the country with $fb_country_str (which in this case it should update)
                $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE highscore SET country = $fb_country_str WHERE fbID = $user");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

$user - You a re treating it as a boolean (in the if statement) then a number (If I assume correctly) in the query

Comment: even if $user is number ... if condition will evaluate it false in case `if($user)` is `if(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your last if condition

```
if ($country != $fb_country_str) 
{ 
//if the country is NOT the same, update the country with $fb_country_str (which in this case it should update)
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE highscore SET country = $fb_country_str WHERE fbID = $user");
}
```